# Msys2 compiled C++ too slow

Tags: c++, g++, msys2

I'm experiencing trouble with my code execution. I'm on Windows, trying to work in C/C++, so I've decided to install gcc/g++ via [Msys2](https://www.msys2.org/). I've followed through the entire process without any errors or warning.

My problem is that the compiled code is painfully slow to execute and I have no idea/clue as to where it comes from... In the command prompt, when launching the code it does nothing for 40sec, then do what is expected and I can't wrap my head around it.

To be precise, here is my test code, some of you may find it familiar: (again it REALLY takes 40sec to execute completely)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

My goal is to be able to use Visual Studio Code as an environment for C/C++, being able to write code but also test it. So I've made it, and to be fair, it works. But that was so slow I had to verify if it came from VSC or from the compiled code. It appears that it comes from the code...

If you have any idea, or maybe even better, solutions, please share them! Many thanks!

EDIT: I've been messing around with this and it appears that when you compile and run for the first time, it is really slow, but then, for the new times it is as fast as we could expect it to be. Not anywhere nearer to the solution but if it can help...

Comment: If you are asking if this is normal, it is not.  Your 40sec delay is caused by something not mentioned here.  A misbehaving virus scanner, perhaps?

Comment: Fire up your old friend and mine Task Manager, [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) if you've got it and start gathering information. If it is the AV software holding things up, you might be able to see it spinning. If you can't see anything soaking time, something like [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) may help you see where things hung.

Comment: I would expect the AV Scanner is the most likely cause. Some will run unknown executables in a sandbox.

Comment: Have you tried completely disabling the AV scanner? Have you tried building your code from the command line directly?

Comment: The behavior described in the edit would seem consistent with an acting-up AV scanner.

Comment: I can't spot anything particular in my Task Manager, and my computer doesn't seem to be hard pressed in memory or processor or anything...
How could I spot the AV scan?

@drescherjm I'm building from the command line already... Starting to loose hope...

Comment: Its not really a scan. Some AV like aVast will intercept the running of an executable and if its signature does not match ones it has in its database it will run your unknown application in a sandbox to detect and prevent it from preforming malicious actions.

Comment: Does `gcc -v` take a long time or is it instant?

Comment: @drescherjm you were right, all it took was moving the current folder to the AV white list as mentioned in my post answer

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to most of the comments below my post, I've been oriented to verify my antivirus behavior. Adding the working folder to the whitelist (no real time analysis) of the antivirus solved the problem.

Many thanks to @DrewDormann, @user4581301, @NathanPierson and @drescherjm!

Comment: Some days I feel that it would be more efficient in terms of computing resources to simply... [remove](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U6cake3bwnY) all malicious actors. Be great for the environment, too.

Comment: Why haven't we thought of that? Let's do it, then! I call the East, you take the West, let's convince everyone!